# Youtube LiveBroadcasts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have JavaScript code that allows you to take a video from the webcam. I would like to know how to send the stream directly to my youtube channel?

```
var start = function(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function (stream) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
          // sender stream in my YouTube LiveBroadcasts
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Something went wrong!");
        });
    }
}
```